# Is hurting an animal for self defense allowed in Islam?

Tags: sharia, dogs, self-defense

Is hurting an animal for self defense allowed in Islam?

Our local government has failed to control dog population in our city with over a 100,000 dogs roaming around a lot of them being rabid, often bite people, is it allowed in this situation to stone the dog for self defence.

Comment: Well your local government should intervene and if necessary these dogs should be killed, as they are a danger for people and animals etc. So even an offensive kind of self defense would be necessary and mandatory!

Comment: @Medi1Saif, I hope they did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a general Islamic law, self-defense is considered as a Wajib (mandatory) practice. Then in the mentioned issue, you are allowed to throw stone at rabid dog. Of course you should pay attention that do the mentioned act in cases that you have no other chooses (such as escaping..), otherwise annoying animals would be considered as a bad practice (or even haram) in the cases which it is not emergency to ...